# Can the Soulknife's psychic blades be used with extra attack as a thrown weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, multiattack

The [Soulknife](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Soulknife) (p63 TCoE) has the ability to manifest [Psychic Blades](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Soulknife)

> Whenever you take the Attack action, you can manifest a psychic blade from your free hand
> and make the attack with that blade...

> ...The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target...

> ...After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged attack with a second psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, provided your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4, instead of 1d6.

Can you attack multiple times with it as a thrown weapon, if you have the [Extra attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#ExtraAttack) or [Haste spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It seems you get one and only one psychic blade attack per attack action

You've already quoted the most important part, which is that the psychic blade vanishes *immediately* after the attack is made. This means that each psychic blade you create is usable for exactly one attack. That, taken together with the fact that you can only manifest 1 blade per attack action, means **you only get one psychic blade attack per action**. This means that Extra Attack does not directly benefit the psychic blades. However, if you have multiple attacks per action from Extra Attack or some other feature, you are free to draw a real knife and use that for the 2nd attack of your action, and then use your bonus action to make a 3rd attack with your bonus action psychic knife. This actually appears to be a decent way of making a thrown weapon build work with Extra Attack, since you can get your full round of 3 attacks while only needing to draw one weapon per turn (and you don't have to carry a backpack full of daggers).

On the other hand, "one psychic blade attack per action" works directly in your favor when you bring in *Haste*, Action Surge, or any other effect that grants additional actions. Because you get to manifest a new blade "whenever you take the Attack action", each additional action you take gives you one additional psychic blade to attack with. This is perfect for *Haste*, which only gives you one additional attack anyway, and OK but not ideal for Action Surge, since you won't be able to use Extra Attack with your extra action with only one psychic blade.

Comment: With Action Surge, you could attack twice with Extra Attack by attacking once with each of the psychic blades you're dual weilding.

Answer (score 1):

> Also at 3rd level, You can manifest your psionic power as shimmering blades of psychic energy. Whenever you take the Attack action, you can manifest a psychic blade from your free hand and make the attack with that blade. This magic blade is a simple melee weapon with the finesse and thrown properties. It has a normal range of 60 feet and no long range, and on a hit, it deals psychic damage equal to 1d6 plus the ability modifier you used for the attack roll. The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target, and it leaves no mark on its target if it deals damage.
>
> After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged weapon attack with a second psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, provided your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4, instead of 1d6.”

So long as you have a free hand you can summon the blade into it and make an attack.

Comment: I don't believe this is generally correct.  The feature allows you to create a blade "when you take the Attack action" (as well as when you take a bonus action mentioned), not "when you attack".  As the other answer says, after you take your first attack, you won't be holding any psychic blades, and cannot create one for an Extra Attack attack.